# Detect leaving a buried element - Jquery

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, css

At the moment I have an image, and when the user puts their mouse over it, using Jquery I place a transparent div over the image. The problem is that this triggers the mouseout event. I want the transparent div to leave when the mouse moves away from the image. What is the best way to detect this if there is a transparent div covering the image. Hope that made at least some sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the div is the same size as the image, you could hide the div on the div's own mouseout event.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe that after half an hour of head scratching that never crossed my mind, it's so simple. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

add the mouseOut listener to the div instead.

Answer (score 1):

Check out mouseenter rather than mouseleave. If you wrap the image and the transparent div inside a containing div, then look for mouseenter on that div, you will get the desired behaviour. Mouseenter behaviour bubbles up through child elements, and sounds like exactly what you need.

[Mouseenter from JQuery API site](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)

Answer (score 0):

There are some plugins available to do this trick (captions on mouse-over) like:

http://buildinternet.com/2009/03/sliding-boxes-and-captions-with-jquery/

http://www.chazzuka.com/blog/?p=138